# Crystax wcsncasecmp was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, android-ndk, wchar

I'm making a android app with [crystax](http://www.crystax.net/en/android/ndk) Improved Android NDK, and I did it:

```
 #include <wchar.h>
 wcsncasecmp(L"", L"", 0);
```

and I getting the follow error:

```
jni/MooveBike.cpp:30:34: error: 'wcsncasecmp' was not declared in this scope
```

what i did wrong?

Comment: what platform are you developing on?

Comment: @ChrisBain minimum api 9 target 17 and ndk android-ndk-r8-crystax-1 android api 9 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be such error if all done right. The only case when I were able get the same error as you mentioned, is if wchar.h were included into function body (which is wrong and shouldn't be done) instead of global scope. Include wchar.h at the top of source file (like other include files) and it will work.

Comment: I also was using the ndk-build binary of android-ndk folder and not of crystax-ndk folder.